# How to make 2 apps I'm writing exchange information?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data

How can one app I am writing access data stored or created by another app I wrote? basically how can they communicate with each other?

Comment: Apps cannot access each others data, you will have to use some server/cloud solution that both apps can access.

Comment: unless you put whatever data you want to share to a file or database  or cloud service, you may not able to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom url scheme:

Here is a simple example:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/

Comment: Yep, and one trick that I see apps do is to use URL schemes to bounce back-and-forth between the apps. i.e. App1 calls App2 to do something, and the URL contains a parameter that indicates to App2 that it should  launch App1's URL when finished. The Dropbox SDK does this to facilitate "connecting" your app to a Dropbox account.

Answer (score 2):

A few options:

- URL schemes. You can send data by encoding it as a URL and open the other app
- Your own server. You have a centralised/cloud server and that represents the "truth" that's used by both apps
- iCloud. Multiple apps can access the same iCloud data (this is certaily true for the key-value store, I'm pretty sure it's also true for Core Data syncing)